# How can I find out the PID of the affected process in signal handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals

I've got the following signal handler:

```
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)
```

The signal handler registration is the following:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

How can I find out the affected process ID in the signal handler when the SIGINT happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `os.getpid()`:

```
import os, sys, signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C (pid = {0})'.format(pid))
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid